# How to/Where to find MySQL templates for Toad Data Modeler

Tags: mysql, database-design, toad

I have recently install Toad Data Modeler 5.3.4 and it only has Oracle data model templates. Where can I find and import the MySQL data templates so that I can create MySQL database models. I have Googled and looked on the Toad World website.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for work with MySQL. It is an excellent, free and Open Source tool for working with MySQL databases. As well as that, there isn't a one-to-one correspondence between Oracle and MySQL datatypes. Some samples/examples are available [here](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20workbench%20templates%20samples).

[EDIT] Ooops - just realised that there is Toad for MySQL, so presumably the data types will be appropriate.However, I would just suggest that the best people to make admin tools for a given database are the actual manufacturers of that database - Toad started as a specialised Oracle product and probably still carries some baggage from those origins, whereas MySQL Workbench has always been a specialised MySQL tool.

Having said that, compiling it from source is a tricky business with numerous components and unless you're a guru, I'd use the pre-compiled version. If you are interested, you might like to look at [this site](http://mysqlworkbench.org/) which is a kind of MySQL Workbench fanzine. This [site](http://planet.mysql.com/) is also of interest to those working with MySQL.

Comment: Hey @Vérace , thank you for your response! I would use it if possible, but being that this is an enterprise environment, my hands a little tied. It would take a while before I could get MySQL Workbench approved for use. I know that Toad Data Modeler can do what I want, but just seem to be missing how to load MySQL templates into it.

Comment: It  may be that Toad for MySQL is limited and can't load templates? I don't know much about it. Another good tool is SQuirreL SQL, but I'm not sure about the template situation there. A Google gave me [this](http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/Content/Data_Grid/Use_Import_and_Export_Templates.htm) and [this](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-data-modeler/f/30/t/2586) might be of interest?

Comment: It may be that Toad for MySQL is limited and can't load templates? I don't know much about it. Another good tool is SQuirreL SQL, but I'm not sure about the template situation there. A Google gave me [this](http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/Content/Data_Grid/Use_Import_and_Export_Templates.htm) and [this](http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/Content/Data_Grid/Use_Import_and_Export_Templates.htm) might be of interest? As an aside, I presume that your employers give you command line access - yes? If so, why can't they let  you use a tool which only provides a GUI to that command line? PHBs-Grr.

Comment: This is actually a question related to **Toad Data Modeler**. Oracle setting are pre-loaded for me, but I would like to add MySQL. I know it's possible, I just can't find the requisite templates.

Comment: Check the two Google references that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "templates", but TDM supports MySQL as well as many other DBMS.

Maybe MySQL wasn't enabled in your installation. This can be changed in

Settings -> Add/Remove database

[image]

Once the database is enabled it will show up when you create a new model:

[image]

The screenshots were taken with TDM 6.0 but the dialogs were the same in 5.3